# Magento worldpay Error ukdc1-pz-cen09:callbackFailureEmail-1312:MerchReq-626-40

Tags: magento, worldpay

I have installed WorldPay Extension and its was working fine but from last few days I face issue. Response URL not call and through fatal error
I got email each time from worldpay and they mentioned they got following error 
"
failed CAUSED BY Received fatal 
alert: internal_error
Server Reference: ukdc1-pz-cen09:callbackFailureEmail-1312:MerchReq-626-40
"

can one have idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: This is related to programing because there is fatal error that send by magneto file. The file that call by worldpay response.

Comment: You're dealing with a computer. Computers must be programmed. But that doesn't mean your question is about programming.